# How can this intransitive verb be used transitively here?

Tags: grammar, transitivity

The sentence in question:

> 中には、おんぶを怖がる子どももいます

[Full context](https://www3.nhk.or.jp/news/web_tokushu/2018_0521.html?utm_int=news_contents_tokushu_004)

My attempt at translation:
"On average, there are also children which fear piggybackriding".

In [the jisho translation](https://jisho.org/search/%E4%B8%AD%E3%81%AB%E3%81%AF%E3%80%81%E3%81%8A%E3%82%93%E3%81%B6%E3%82%92%E6%80%96%E3%81%8C%E3%82%8B%E5%AD%90%E3%81%A9%E3%82%82%E3%82%82%E3%81%84%E3%81%BE%E3%81%99), 怖がる is described as intransitive. Since を is used, I assume theres a transitive use in front of us though. Is Jisho wrong here or is this a regular "ambiguity" in contemporary japanese grammar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe 怖がる is a transitive verb. 明鏡国語辞典 lists it as a 他動詞:

> こわがる【怖がる（▿恐がる）】〘**他**五〙

[中]{なか}には means "among (them)". 中には～～もいる/ある means "Some of them ~~".

> 中にはパイロットになった者もいた。
>   Some of them became pilots.
>   (from Shogakukan's *Progressive J-E Dictionary*)

So your example can translate to:

> "Among the children (in 久宝まぶねこども園), some are scared of riding piggyback."
>   "Some of the children (in the nursery) are scared of riding piggyback."